# Kubernetes iptables - should the master node be running pods?

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, flannel

In my kubernetes cluster I have a flannel overlay configured. the `iptables` on the master node and the minions are not the same. I understand that this is by design but it creates the problem that pods can't run on the master node: on the master, external IP addresses (for a service) are not resolved.

On the minions there is a `KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER` and `KUBE-PORTALS-HOST` chain which redirects service cluster and external IP addresses. Static routes redirect this traffic to the master which actually resolves the addresses. 
On the master there isn't the 2 chains mentioned above but instead there is a `KUBE-SERVICES` chain which resolves services IPs to pod IP addresses.

Is there a way to configure the master node to have the chains that the nodes have as well as the service resolution chain too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pods are running on Kubernetes nodes (formerly called minions) but not on masters, see [Kubernetes architecture](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/architecture.md). You may also find the [debugging Service doc](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/debugging-services/) helpful.